# jQuery context callback

Tags: jquery, scope

Is there a way to run set of listeners in a other context than "document"?

This would be a nice way to limit the selectors.

Something like this:

```
$(".main", function(){
   $(".child-1").click(function() {  /* .... */ });  // .main .child
   $(".child-2").click(function() {  /* .... */ });  // .main .child-2
   $(".child-3").click(function() {  /* .... */ });  // .main .child-3
});
```

Instead of:

```
$(".main .child-1").click(function() {  /* .... */ });  // .main .child
$(".main .child-2").click(function() {  /* .... */ });  // .main .child-2
$(".main .child-3").click(function() {  /* .... */ });  // .main .child-3
```

By using this you could use scope instead of one big (document) scope.

So, those this exist in someway in jQuery?? Tried google, couldn't really find anything..

Comment: In a general sense, not in the way you've shown, but the [2nd argument to `jQuery`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1) is used to provide context (in the form of a jQuery object or DOM node). But if you only care about event handling, you can delegate them at any point in the DOM tree with the `.on()` method.

Comment: This can't be done. The best you can get is `$(".child-1", this)`, which already exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest thing would be something like this

```
var $ctx = $('#context');

$ctx.find('.something').click(function(){ });
```

Comment: `$('.something',$ctx).click(...`

Comment: @JanDvorak jQuery will do the very same thing anyway

Comment: Yeah, but it's less characters that way :-)

Comment: @JanDvorak I just wanted to make it as readable as possible for someone who hasn't seen it before ;)

Answer (score -1):

```
$('.main').on("click", ".child-1", function() {

}).on("click",".child-2", function() {

}).on("click",".child-3", function() {

});
```

Or, if they all do the same...

```
$('.main').on("click", ".child-1, .child-2, .child-3", function() {

});
```

http://jsperf.com/on-click-performance - you'll see this way is quicker than the other solution.

Comment: Note the semantics is sligtly different, but still a nice candidate.

Comment: When passing 3 arguments to `on`, it will behave just like the deprecated `live()`. Isnt this a bit excessive when the elements arent dynamically generated?

Comment: I'm not aware of performance concerns, but it's a possibility. I just like the code readability.

Comment: @Johan `live` wasn't deprecated because it performed delegation; it got deprecated because of the way it was called.

Comment: Read what I said. Im not suggesting live(), im just using it as a reference. Also, click isnt deprecated, its just a shorthand for `$(selector).on('click', function);`. Just as the deprecated `bind()` was

Comment: @Johan `bind` isn't deprecated, just superseeded.

Comment: @Johan `$(document).bind('ready'` was deprecated, but so was `$(document).on('ready'`.

Comment: @JanDvorak Ok my bad. Should have called it "superseeded" :)

Comment: @Johan did you downvote because it causes event delegation? There is no performance hit to delegation (it can be quite the opposite), so I oppose this downvote reason.

Comment: @Johan `$('.main').on("click",".child-1, .child-2, .child-3",...)` is slightly slower then `$('.main').on("click",".child-1",...)` because the first one is a more complex selector that needs to be tested at click. but for events like `click`, `mousedown`, `mouseup` you won't notice a difference. for events like `mousemove`, `mouseenter`, `mouseleave` it probably will be noticeable. certain events like `focus`, `blur`, `change` won't work in every browsers using delegates

Comment: @JanDvorak I downvotes because OP is miss-using the method. Regardless on how performance is affected, a delegated-event approach is not necessary here.

Comment: @Johan definitely not neccessary, IMHO not a reason enough to downvote.

Comment: @thedixon note that you only measure the event attachment performance. Event registration performance (that is, when it actually fires) is more important here.

Comment: If I'm down voted here due to a minimalistic performance hit on event registration due to delegation, then so be it.